# Packaging Rspec Shared Example Groups as a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I have created several shared example groups for Rspec which I would like to reuse in other applications.  The best approach to achieving this seems to be to package these into a gem.  However I can't seem to find a good guide to get me started.  There are several different methods to accomplish this, and all of the guides I've read look like they might be outdated.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Necessary Knowledge

Gems are pretty simple, but there was a huge void in terms of documentation for a really long time. Fortunately that isn't the case anymore.

They're ultimately nothing more than a [.gemspec](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/) file and an understanding of [paths](http://blog.8thlight.com/micah-martin/2007/10/08/micah%27s-general-guidelines-on-ruby-require.html) and dependencies (which you only need to know about if you depend on other gems), though people do expect you to follow certain conventions.

The best walkthrough I've seen is in the [guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/).

For the conventions, the guides have a nice list [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/) and the [packaging standard](https://gist.github.com/361451) is really great as well.

### Further Thoughts

These days, when I want to make a gem, I start off with Bundler (which I prefer over hoe/new gem/jeweler/etc...). [This](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler) Railscast covers how to do that. Now, Bundler will assume you know all sorts of stuff (git, bundler, rake) which I do, so it doesn't bug me anymore, but once upon a time it was too much.

The simple fact of the matter is you don't need Bundler (in the future, if you have dependencies and want to maintain your gem, then it will make your life easier, but for now you don't need it). And you don't need git or any version control if you don't understand it yet (put it on your tolearn list, though). And you don't need rake (its just a CLI to common tasks, but if you don't understand all the crap it's doing, you don't need it, you can test directly with the [rspec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line) binary, you can package your gems directly with the [gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/) binary, you can manage your .gemspec yourself rather than having Rake generate it for you, etc).

The trick is to separate out what all these tools do for you from what you actually want them to do for you. That can be tricky when you don't know how they work / what they do, since they want to do everything. I was able to get past this ignorance by using a really simple tool called [gem this](https://rubygems.org/gems/gem-this) which was a bit dated the last time I used it, but is ultimately about as simple as you can get. [Here](http://rubymanor.org/harder/videos/gem_that/)'s a great video by it's author.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  These are some awesome resources, and I think they've got me 75% of the way there.  However, I can't figure out how to actually integrate my shared example groups into the gem.  I tried placing a test file with a shared example group in it, building and requiring my gem in my main project and RSpec can't find the shared example group I created.

Comment: @helixed and if you follow http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3195424#1036644, it will get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared example in `spec/shared/foo.rb`

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'a foo class' do
...
end
```

`require` the file in your gems `spec/spec_helper.rb` so you can use it in your gems' test specs

Now to make the example available to projects which install the gem you need to add them to your `gemspec` file

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
 ...

 s.files         =  `git ls-files`.split("\n")
 s.files         += `git ls-files -- spec/shared/*.rb`.split("\n")
end
```

you will also need to load it as part of your gem in the test environment.  This is important because the gems' eventual installed path is unknown to the gem.

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'test'
  require File.expand_path('../spec/shared/foo.rb', __dir__)
end
```

Now after installing the gem on your rails project, you can reliably use the shared example in your tests. (assuming the gem is allowed in the test env in your gemfile)

```
RSpec.describe FKlass do
  subject { described_class }

  it_behaves_like 'a foo class'
end
```